# Is there any way to do bit testing in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core, conditionals

I want to do something in tikz that is a bitwise function of a number, e.g.

```
\def\mask{165}   %% = 0xa5 but it looks like TeX doesn't know hex
\foreach \k in {0,...,7} {
    \node[mybox] (b\k) at ($(-\k*\d*2, 0)$) {$b_{\k}$};
    %% if bit \k of \mask is 1:
    \draw[->](b\k) -- ++(0,\d);
    %%
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I am not sure whether I can use `\ifnum` for this purpose; I'm not really familiar with the control structures in TeX.

I found [`intcalc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/intcalc) which has `intcalcShr` (shift right by 1) and `intcalcMod` but I don't know how to shift right by `\k`. Alternatively if I knew an imperative-style for updating a value each time in a loop (`x = x >> 1`) then I think I could figure it out using `intcalc`.

Comment: Pgfmath understands hex `\pgfmathsetmacro\mymask{0xa5}`. Is the mask should be in binary?

Comment: oh, ok, thanks! My real application has more than 8 bits so hex is more convenient than binary.

Comment: With pgfmath, `x >> 1` is `int(x/2)`...

Comment: `\the\numexpr"A5` gives me 165.

Comment: sigh. TeX is both Donald Knuth's blessing and curse to the world.